# CSS border will not show on empty row

Tags: css, html-table, border

I have a table within a table that has 2 rows. I managed to set the border for the top row, which contains a word. However, I just cannot get the border for the bottom empty row to show.

HTML:

```
    <table  class="WorkflowBlock"  width="160" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td valign="Top">
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td height="30" align="Left" class="stepNext" valign="Top" colspan="3">
                        <span title="Order">
                           <ol class="flow" start="4">
                              <li style="font-weight: bold;">Order</li>
                           </ol>
                        </span>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="content">
                     <td>&nbsp;</td>
                     <td><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></td>
                     <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.WorkflowBlock .stepNext {
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
.WorkflowBlock .content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
```

Any idea what did I miss? 
Here's the fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/50qhrph6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
.WorkflowBlock .content {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r0uL3gd3/

Answer (score 0):

You can set border to tr following way.

```
tr {
    outline: thin solid;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50qhrph6/1/)**

Comment: The border should be like the top row, applied from the 'content' class of the css. I am suspecting that something is wrong in the HTML but I just can't put my finger on exactly what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
.WorkflowBlock table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```css
.WorkflowBlock .stepNext {
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
.WorkflowBlock .content{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}

.WorkflowBlock table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table  class="WorkflowBlock"  width="160" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td valign="Top">
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td height="30" align="Left" class="stepNext" valign="Top" colspan="3">
                        <span title="Order">
                           <ol class="flow" start="4">
                              <li style="font-weight: bold;">Order</li>
                           </ol>
                        </span>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="content">
                     <td>&nbsp;</td>
                     <td><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></td>
                     <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps